# How can I access servers on my network when connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

Using openvpn as my vpn client. OS is Debian 10.

Normally I can ssh to any server on my network (192.168.0-2.x).

When I start my vpn, I can still ssh to servers on the same subnet (192.168.0.x) but I can't ssh to servers outside of that subnet (ie 192.168.1.x)

Is there a way to configure openvpn so I can still connect to servers on 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not advised how you normally reach 192.168.1.x etc but the issue here is a simple routing one.

What's likely happening is that 192.168.1.x is being reached through your router - which is also normally your default gateway.  When you  are running your VPN you are replacing your normal default gateway with a new one through the VPN - this causes traffic to be opaque to the router.

The solution is to add static routes to 192.168.1.x with a gateway of your router.  As these routes are more specific then the default gateway they will be preferred for your 192.168.1.x paths.

(I've used 192.168.1.x in my explanation above. The same is true for any affected routes/data you don't want to go through the VPN)

Comment: Thank you! When trying to reach 192.168.0.x, those paths don't go through the router? How am I able to reach 192.168.0.x with no issues while connected to the VPN?

Comment: When the IP address is in the same subnet as your IP address they don't go through the router (at least they are not processed by the parts of the router dealing with routing - they may still go through the built in switch).  My guess is your computers IP address is 192.168.0.? and the netmask is 255.255.255.0 - which would mean 192.168.0.* does not get routed as its on the same LAN.

Comment: Because your IP address is in the same network as the other systems you can currently SSH directly to it your computers OS will add a routing entry into its routing table automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can check here on how to add static route
https://www.linuxtechi.com/add-delete-static-route-linux-ip-command/

sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.43.223 dev enp0s3

you need to check your IP address and eth device, then change accordingly..

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.